# Adding new rows to table when moving between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I'm trying to create a small html project where people can make reservations to a cinema by choosing a movie and seats and then, by clicking a PAY button a new page is shown summing their reservation ,and once a SAVE button is clicked, their reservation should by displayed as a new row in the reservations table.

So I'm having difficulties adding new rows to the table page whenever the button (actually a link to the new page) is clicked in the previous page.

Here's the table part of my orders page (nested inside a div body of course):

```
<table style="border:1px solid black; width:1000px;" id="table">
     <tr bgcolor=#262673 id="tr1" >
          <td align=center style="color:white; font-size:30px;"><b>Movie Name</b>  </td>  
          <td align=center style="color:white; font-size:30px"><b>Number Of Seats</b>  </td>  
          <td align=center style="color:white; font-size:30px"><b>Credit Card Type </b></td>  
    </tr> 
 </table>
```

Here's the link from the previous page called "pay":

```
<a href='myorders.html' onclick="Save();" id="link" ><img src='sobutton.png' height=40 align="right" ></a>
```

and here is my jquery.js file , linked to the orders page:

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
$(document).ready(function () {

    var prev = sessionStorage.getItem("toBeAppended"); // if nothing to append (if it's first time) then prev = null
    if (prev == null)
        prev = " "; // if prev == null, assign to it: " " (space) value
    var numOfSeats = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('checked')).length;
    var card = sessionStorage.getItem("CardName");
    var movie = sessionStorage.getItem("moviename");
    var new1 = "<tr><td>" + movie + "</td><td>" + numOfSeats + "</td><td>" + card + "</td></tr>";
    var oldPlusNew = prev+new1;
    $("#table").addClass("TABLE");
    $("#table").append(oldPlusNew);
    sessionStorage.setItem("toBeAppended", oldPlusNew);
});
}
```

please ignore the sessionstorage parts. The problem is whenever the "pay" page is loaded a row is added to the orders page, and when the orders page is loaded the same thing happens so when I click the button SAVE to move to the orders page from the pay page I see the same row twice, instead of only once..I don't know why this happens so if anyone is willing to help me I'd appreciate it.

P.S the jQuery file is only linked to the orders page and not the pay page

Also, people are given the opportunity to choose a credit card type from a checkbox and I can't seem to retrieve the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

*In response to your second question:*

```
<select id="mySelect">
                <option value="AmericanExpress">American Express</option>
                <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
                <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
            </select>
```

To set the selected option into `sessionStorage` :

```
sessionStorage.setItem("CardName", document.getElementById("mySelect").value);
```

To get the value on another page:

```
var card = sessionStorage.getItem("CardName");
```